# first-of-type not working with class name

Tags: css

I have a lot of element in one div, for ex:

```
<div>
  <p></p>
  <span></span>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <span></span>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
```

I want to select the first `.text` so I used `.text:first-of-type` but it doesn't work, only works for `span:first-of-type`
Can anybody show me how to select the first `.text` ?

Comment: with pure CSS? Not possible. There is no` first-of-class` selector. There's something proposed for CSS4, but you'd have to wait for that to actually be implemented in browsers.

Comment: Not a duplicate - this about first-of-type, the other question is about first-child, also first-of-type is supposed to be there in CSS3

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this correctly. According to the definition:

*The :first-of-type selector in CSS allows you to target the first    occurence of an element within its container. It is defined in the    CSS Selectors Level 3 spec as a “structural pseudo-class”*

...and it should theoretically work in modern browsers. It works for me in the latest versions of Firefox, IE and Chrome

- You're missing a closing `</div>` on the last line of your HTML sample - if this is also in your actual code, does fixing it help?
- Is there another style rule somewhere that's overriding what you're trying to do? What happens if you change the rule to `.text:first-of-type !important`, which will force this rule to have higher priority?
- Maybe if this is nested in other HTML you need to make the .text:first-of-type rule more specific? E.g. is the HTML nested within another element or class - in that case apply the rule by specifying that it applies to anything under that element or class e.g.

  div .text:first-of-type {
    color: red;
  }

Comment: Unlikely for it to be the OP's actual markup. Based on their description, it's very likely there are other divs interfering with the selection.